# How can i build a PHP array with a limited number of possibilities

Tags: php, html, function

I am trying to build a piece of code that prints the line 5 times and there are only two possible outcomes. I also want one of the outcomes to only have the possibility of appearing twice.

```
  <?php
    function abe( $number ) {
    $shoot = Array("alpha", "bravo");

 ?>

        <h1> Hello <?php echo $number; ?> You are on team <?php echo $shoot[array_rand($shoot)]; ?> </h1>

        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <?php abe( '1'); ?>
        <?php abe( '2'); ?>
        <?php abe( '3'); ?>
        <?php abe( '4'); ?>
        <?php abe( '5'); ?>
```

So ideally i want it to print five times only. I also want the "Bravo" to be printed a max amount of 2 times. How can I make it so there are only two instances of Bravo allowed?

```
So this may print....
Hello 1 You are on team alpha
Hello 2 You are on team alpha
Hello 3 You are on team alpha
Hello 4 You are on team alpha
Hello 5 You are on team alpha
```

There is a possibility that Bravo will not even print once. How can i be sure it will print 2 times?

Comment: then you need to keep track of how many times each option has been used, and re-gen the random number if the choice would exceed the limit.  of course, you've got 5 outputs, and only **TWO** options, so the 5th attempt will have nothing to choose from.

Comment: I think you'd end up with number >= 5 as alpha since there is no repeat constraint on it. I haven't written the code, but I'm pretty sure your going to end up using an array that looks something like this :$shoot = Array("alpha"=>array("max"=>0,"current"=>0), "bravo"=>array("max"=>0,"current"=>0));

Comment: Well Alpha can print 3 times and bravo can print 2 times.   If i had this set to have 10 outputs- Alpha would print 8 times and bravo still 2. If that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should be dynamic to deal with any number of players:

```
<?php
function abe( $number ) {
    // Input: Array Input of numbers or Names
    // Output: Team selection for each member of array Alpha||Bravo, where there can only be 2 Bravo
    $b = 0;
    $r = "";
    foreach($number as $n){
        $p = rand(0,1);
        if($p == 1){
            $b++;
        }
        if($b > 2){ $p = 0; }
        $r .= "<h1 pick='$p'>Hello $n You are on team " . (!$p?"Alpha":"Bravo") . " </h1>\r\n";
    }
    return $r;
}

echo abe(array(1,2,3,4,5));
?>
```

**EDIT**

Per your comments, here is another version that will force Bravo 2 times:

```
<?php
function abe( $number ) {
    // Input: Array Input of numbers or Names
    // Output: Team selection for each member of array Alpha||Bravo, where there can only be 2 Bravo
    $b = 0;
    $c = count($number);
    $r1 = rand(1,$c);
    $r2 = rand(1,$c);
    if($r1 == $r2){
        $r2++;
        if($r2 > $c){
            $r2 -= 2;
        }
    }
    $r = "";
    foreach($number as $k => $n){
        if($k == $r1 || $k == $r2){
            $r .= "<h1 pick='$k'>Hello $n You are on team Bravo</h1>\r\n";
        } else {
            $r .= "<h1 pick='$k'>Hello $n You are on team Alpha</h1>\r\n";
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

echo abe(array(1,2,3,4,5));
?>
```

Comment: This is a step forward i believe. There is still a probability though that "Alpha" will print all 5 times. I wonder how to force it so that Bravo must print twice.

Comment: So you want to have 2 members randomly be picked as Bravo every time? the rest will always be Alpha?

Comment: yes, I have been trying to make up a challenge for myself and this is one i can't figure out. Forcing it to have 2 members be "bravo" and the rest be alpha.

Comment: Did my edit help? If it answers the question, please mark it.

Comment: this is sort've working, it shoots out "Bravo" twice sometimes and sometimes it shoots it out once.

Comment: Should not do that ever. If the 2 picks are the same it bumps the next one up 1. If that's higher than the count, it decrements by 2. So if they both picked 5, the 2nd would go to 6, 6 > 5, it would bump to 4. If they were both 1, the 2nd would bump to 2, 2 < 5 and would just continue. How often do you see it just give 1 Bravo?

Comment: like 50% of the time. Did you run it?